# Do I need a transit visa for transiting Munich and Dublin

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, transit-visas, ireland

I have a Canadian student visa on Indian passport. I am travelling on Lufthansa airlines which has two stops - one is Munich and other is Dublin before reaching Canada. Do i need transit visa?

Comment: Can you post your itinerary? Transit without visa is only possible in Dublin Terminal 2 and that too for flights on the same day (according to Timatic). Your Canadian visa should enable you to transit Munich without a visa.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.